# How to set z-index of different shapes in Cesium?

Tags: z-index, cesiumjs

I have plotted a cylinder at some latitude/longitude and altitude with certain radius and height for the cylinder.

I have then plotted a image using billboard. The position of the image is inside the cylinder already plotted. The image comes behind the cylinder. Is it any way to plot the image above the cylinder just like z-index property in CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [cesium: How to set Z-index of different shapes in Cesium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910276/cesium-how-to-set-z-index-of-different-shapes-in-cesium)